# Encoding Parameter passed as URL- Alternate options?

Tags: java, url, encoding, url-encoding

I am passing a String value in a URL
eg: **http://localhost:8080/webservice/useradmin/a%bghijlk123/0978+gh**

The String "ab%ghijlk123/0978+gh" breaks the URL.
What are the available options to overcome this.
Is encoding the string the only option? There must be minimal code change. Any server side configurations can be used to achieve this?
Kindly provide suggestions please.

Comment: How did you come up with this string at first place (what is the plain text and encoding method)? Can you share the code you tried so far?

Comment: this string is randomly generated .....used base64 encoding scheme..i need other options than encoding

Comment: I think you should remove slashes in your generated string. Because / is reserved for paths in URLs. You can use alphanumeric plus $-_.+!*'(),

Comment: Thanks Thush..but its randomly generated by someone else..i cannot change it

Answer (score 1):

> Is encoding the string the only option?

It is the only correct option.

Use `URLEncoder.encode("ab%ghijlk123/0978+gh", "UTF-8")`,
which will give you `ab%25ghijlk123%2F0978%2Bgh`, for a full URL of:

```
http://localhost:8080/webservice/useradmin/ab%25ghijlk123%2F0978%2Bgh
```

---

The URL `http://localhost:8080/webservice/useradmin/a%bghijlk123/0978+gh` is invalid.

The URL specification ([RFC3986](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt)) says that path segments (the values separated by a `/`) may only consist of:

```
ALPHA:           "a"-"z", "A"-"Z"
DIGIT:           "0"-"9"
Special chars:   - . _ ~ ! $ & ' ( ) * + , ; = : @
pct-encoded:     "%" HEXDIG HEXDIG
```

Values that has to be disallowed because they have other meanings are: `/` (path separator), `?` (start of query), `#` (start of fragment), and `%` (start of 2-digit hex encoded char).

As you can see, the `%` sign is only allowed as a percent-encoded character, so `%bg` makes the URL invalid.

If the part after the `useradmin/` is supposed to be the *value* `ab%ghijlk123/0978+gh`, then it *must* be encoded as shown above.

If the server rejects that as "400:Bad request", then the server is in error.

Comment: I tried the same URLEncoder...the thing is % symbol is not getting accepted in URL..im getting 400:Bad request if i use the URL   `http://localhost:8080/webservice/useradmin/ab%25ghijlk123%2F0978%2Bgh` ...if i remove the % symbol, the request reaches the server successfully